# Numpy speed for computing metrics (like np.mean) over multiple axes vs. single axis

Tags: python, numpy

Currently, I am working with video data and therefore I am performing statistical operations on multiple frames at once. During a debugging session I observed that the computation for numpy statistics (mean computation) in this case) over multiple axes takes longer when computed directly over the desired axes compared to computing it over each axis separately one after the other. I created a simple example to explain my observations.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import numpy as np

rnd_frames = np.random.randn(100, 128, 128, 3)
n_reps = 1000

# -----------------------------------
# mean computation over multiple axes
# -----------------------------------
# all axes at once
ts = timer()
for i in range(n_reps):
    mean_1 = np.mean(rnd_frames, axis=(1, 2))
print('Mean all at once: ', (timer()-ts)/n_reps)
# one after the other
ts = timer()
for i in range(n_reps):
    mean_2 = np.mean(rnd_frames, axis=1)
    mean_2 = np.mean(mean_2, axis=1)
print('Mean one after the other: ', (timer()-ts)/n_reps)

print('Difference in means: ', np.sum(np.abs(mean_1-mean_2)))
```

The difference is very small and results from float64 precision.

Does someone have an explanation for this? As the time differences are quite significant: **One after the other is 10x faster**

I wonder if this is some kind of bug? Can anyone explain this.

Comment: I got `Difference in stddevs:  281.6046770112792`. For the mean is around `e-15`.

Comment: about the time: I increased the array `rnd_frames = np.random.randn(100, 128, 128, 30)` and then the execution time was of the same magnitude. The amount of terms along an axis affects the execution time

Comment: @cards the difference for stddevs is high as computing the stddev one axis after the other is mathamticall not the same as doing it at the same time. The example was nonsense... I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time for 2 axes is the same as for a 1 axis on the equivalent reshape:

```
In [7]: timeit mean_1 = np.mean(rnd_frames, axis=(1, 2))
54.2 ms ± 202 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [11]: timeit mean_3 = np.mean(rnd_frames.reshape(100,-1,3), axis=1)
54.5 ms ± 142 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [12]: rnd_frames.reshape(100,-1,3).shape
Out[12]: (100, 16384, 3)
```

As you note this is quite a bit larger than a sequential calculation:

```
In [13]: %%timeit
    ...: mean_2 = np.mean(rnd_frames, axis=1)
    ...: mean_2 = np.mean(mean_2, axis=1)
7.63 ms ± 49.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Without getting deep into the woods of compiled code it's hard to say why there this difference.  While "avoiding loops" is a common performance strategy in `numpy`, that applies mostly to "many loops on a simple task".  A few loops on a complex task can be faster.  I'm not sure that applies here, but I'm not surprised that there are differences like this.

We could also explore whether putting those 2 loops at the end (inner most), or beginning of the dimensions shows this difference or not.

### edit

If I move the 2 axes to either the beginning, or end, the time difference is much smaller.  There's something about having that small size 3 dimension at the end (inner most) that's making your example unusually slow.

Comment: That's right. I think it's still quite interesting as this small last dimension is usual for image/video processing. I would have expected numpy to have some "intrinsic optimization" implemented to deal with such a case in the "best" (in this case the fastest) way.